Next.js 14 / Shadcn - Adding vertical scroll bar to a preview image
How do I add a vertical scroll bar to a preview image?

I have tried adding the following code but failed.
  <ModalDocumentView isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
    <div className="flex flex-col h-full ">
      <div className="relative h-full p-10">
        <Image
          objectFit="none"
          layout="fill"
          alt="Image preview"
          src={document.invoiceUrl}
          className="overflow-y-auto h-full w-screen overscroll-y-auto object-top"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="pt-6 space-x-2 flex items-center justify-end w-full ">
        <Button disabled={loading} variant={"outline"} onClick={onClose}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ModalDocumentView>

